# Segmentation fault when loading a GeoJson

Tags: python, json, geojson, geopandas

I have a problem while loading a JSON document with geopandas but when calling `data = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file(json_data)`, I get a `segmentation fault`.

My JSON seems to be valid and I don't know how to do it without using geopandas.

Here is my GeoJSON : http://pastebin.com/50fKz2T9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My JSON seems to be valid and I don't know how to do it without using geopandas.

There is a site to test that: [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/). According to this validator the document is invalid.

```
Line 5: GeoJSON features must have a type=feature property
Line 5: "properties" property required
Line 5: "geometry" property required
```

Comment: Yeah I have to edit that, I had to reduce the JSON due to stackoverflow size limit policy

Comment: Have you checked the original document with the validator? In case the document passes the check please update the question with a minimal example that still crashes Python or if the segfault only occurs with the large file publish the file on a pastebin.

Comment: I tried with jsonlint.com but not geojsonlint.com, it was  invalid. But I still have the same error

Comment: Please reread you comment. You say jsonlint.com claimed the document is invalid. This means the document is no valid JSON and since GeoJSON is a subset of JSON it will also be invalid GeoJSON. Note that jsonlint.com does not check GeoJSON specific rules.

Comment: Sorry I was (somehow) confused, the geojson was invalid, that was the source of the error.